# React-native duplicating css class names

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I'm trying to understand the best practice for naming component styles in react-native. I understand that style-sheets are scoped at component level but I want to understand if i have two different components whether its bad to use the same css class name for different styles in different components. For example:

component one:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    </View>
  )
}

const componentOneStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
});
```

component two:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    </View>
  )
}

const componentTwoStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  }
});
```

Given this example is it ok to use container for both these components or would it be better practice to use containerOne and containerTwo.

Comment: Imo it's ok to use the container name for both components, at the end those two are separete components and you don't have to take care and remember all containers(numbers) that you defined.

Comment: As long as the name is semantic then it's fine.